# How to make a field read-only inside a CreateView

Tags: django

I am a Django beginner and I am trying to make read-only a 'price' field for an order. I think, based on what I have understood, this cannot be done inside the model itself, but rather inside a form.

Since I am using a CreateView generic view, I thought this could have been done by setting the attribute disabled equal to True, as said [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled).

so what I have done is, in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import Order
from django import forms


# Create your views here.
class CreateOrderView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'home.html'
    meal_price = forms.DecimalField(disabled=True)
    fields = [
        'meal_name',
        'meal_price',
        'restaurant',
        'customer',
    ]
```

But this doesn't work.
Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from restaurant.models import Restaurant
from account.models import Customer


# Create your models here.
class Order(models.Model):
    meal_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    meal_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

Can anybody give me a hint?
Please consider that I am still learning so I would prefer coded answers to descriptive ones.

Comment: You can't do that in the view, you need to do that in the form. Your statement creating a `meal_price` form field in the view does nothing because a view doesn't have fields. So you should create a custom `OrderForm` (a `ModelForm`) and set `form_class = OrderForm` (and remove `fields` and `model` from your `CreateView` because that's not in the form).

Comment: But my main problem is: what are you going to show in that field if you disable it? Since this is a `CreateView`, there isn't an `Order` object yet, so all fields are empty, including the `meal_price`. So why show a disabled empty field in the first place? Where do you want to get its value from?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to dirkgroten, I have worked out the answer. 
Basically what is needed (in my case) is:

an Order model in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from restaurant.models import Restaurant
from account.models import Customer


# Create your models here.
class Order(models.Model):
    meal_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    meal_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

an OrderForm(ModelForm) in forms.py that modifies the price field setting the disabled attribute to true

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Order

from django import forms
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    meal_price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            'meal_name',
            'meal_price',
            'restaurant',
            'customer',
        ]
```

an OrderView(CreateView) in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import OrderForm


# Create your views here.
class OrderView(CreateView):
    form_class = OrderForm
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by extending `CreateView.get_form()`. Using the OP's example:

```py
class CreateOrderView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'home.html'
    fields = ['meal_name', 'meal_price', 'restaurant', 'customer']

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['meal_price'].disabled = True
        return form
```

With regard to [@dirkgroten's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179813/how-to-make-a-field-read-only-inside-a-createview/77585507#comment104583827_59179813): You can set an initial value for the disabled field, e.g. by extending `CreateView.get_initial()`.

Here's a more generic example that uses a custom `readonly_fields` class attribute and sets the initial values based on url query parameters, as in `https://.../?meal_price=10.99`:

```py
class CreateOrderView(CreateView):
    ...
    readonly_fields = ['meal_price']

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class=form_class)
        for field_name in self.readonly_fields:
            # make the field read-only
            form.fields[field_name].disabled = True
        return form

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        for field_name in self.readonly_fields:
            # set the field's initial value based on url query
            initial[field_name] = self.request.GET.get(field_name)
        return initial
```

This could be improved with some additional validation, etc., but the basic principle should be clear.

For some fields it would make more sense to get the initial value from a url path parameter, as in `some/path/<int:param>/`, and `initial['some_field'] = self.kwargs['param']`.

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with Django's CreateView but from what I read it works similar to a separate form. You could try something like this:

```py
class CreateOrderView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'home.html'
    fields = [
        'meal_name',
        'meal_price',
        'restaurant',
        'customer',
    ]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateOrderView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['meal_price'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

From my experience, the disabled attribute will be good for security reasons as far as protecting against the user editing the HTML and changing the value. However you won't be able to access this value when passed into a clean method. If you need to perform actions on the value you should change 'disabled' to 'readonly', but you won't have the same data protection that disabled offers.

Comment: A `CreateView` doesn't have form fields. `fields` is the list of strings for the fields to be included in the form. So `self.fields['meal_price']` is going to raise an error that list only takes integer as subscript, not string. Because `self.fields` is the list defined above, not a dictionary.

Comment: So basically a CreateView is too simple and the form should be separated in order to take advantage of additional functions.

Comment: Yes, the `CreateView` also takes a `form_class` attribute, that lets you specify the form you want to use. In which case you need to remove the `model` and `fields` attributes (you put those in the `Meta` of your form).